# Drupal custom query for fetching few fields data from content types

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6

I want to fetch all data from a particular content type e.g. **xyz_movie**. I need title of the movie, its type (sci-fi / drama etc) and created date
I have access to the database only (but cant download db only read access), i can't connect to the prod server database from my localhost so i cant write drupal code for this.

Can anyone help me in writing query for fetching all data from a content type 
**xyz_movie**

Now i am trying with the following query,

```
SELECT * FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {node_revisions} nr USING(nid, vid) INNER JOIN {xyz_movie} q USING(nid, vid) WHERE n.type = 'xyz_movie' AND n.status = 1;


SELECT * FROM node n INNER JOIN node_revision nr USING(nid, vid) LEFT JOIN xyz_movie q USING(nid, vid) WHERE n.type='xyz_movie' ;
```

Comment: Do you have access to the back-end?

Comment: yes, I can run select queries and export..

Comment: No, I mean access to Drupal's back-end. Can you login and use administration pages? If so, mu suggestion is to use views for reading content.

Comment: yes, i can login to the admin panel

Comment: Thanks...will take quick tutorial on Views for this